# Excel .cell(x,y) Conversion

Tags: excel, type-conversion, vba

I'm getting a compile error here saying "Object doesn't support this property or method" on line 4

I'm guessing that the X in .cell(x,y) cannot be taken as an integer? What would I need to change this variable type to?

```
Private Function FinalizeTemplate(col As Integer)

    With Worksheets(1)
        .cell(col, 2).Value = "A"
        .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 10.3
        .cell(col + 1, 2).Value = "B"
        .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 14
        .cell(col + 3, 2).Value = "C"
        .Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 12.57
        .cell(col + 4, 2).Value = "Type"
        .Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 8
        .cell(col + 5, 2).Value = "Valid/Invalid"
        .Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 11.71
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: You need to use `.Cells()`, note the `s`.

Comment: Wow... not sure how I missed that syntax error! Thank you! :)

Comment: @BruceWayne Do you know if it's possible to change the column width size with a method like this?

Comment: What do you mean - does your code not do it?

Comment: My question is that if I use .Columns(1) would that still work; I tested it myself and it does work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per BruceWayne's comment, the issue was it must be .cells() and not .cell()